# How to best interact with a large collection of images in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, image

In my future iOS app, the app will constantly be interacting and retrieving data from a large amount of images (around 1500). I wanted to ask what is the best way to store them in my app and interact with them.

Thank you.

UPDATE: My intent is to extract images from that collection and place them in a UIImageView. 
More specifically, the user will be making a selection and according to that selection a specific image(s) from my database will be extracted and placed in the UIImageView.

The concept is simple, however I'm new to iOS and not sure what's the best way to store images here.

P.S. The images should be stored locally and not localized somewhere in the web

Comment: You may want to be more specific as to your intentions with each image. Display? Modify them? Hard to tell you how to handle them if we have no idea how they're going to be used.

Comment: More detail needed. Are the images a static resource or downloaded later?  What kind of "data" are you retrieving from them ?

Comment: I've added some more description to my questions. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these images have to be local and readily accessible, there may not be much you can do other than modifying the images to be of smaller size and perhaps change the formatting, but both of these directly depend on how you plan to use these images. If you are simply displaying them, you may want to look into the different image formats and see what quality or size you would be willing to accept.

Comment: Thank you for your reply KineticStack. But, I think my question is still a bit unclear. I'm wondering not how to interact with them or what kind of interaction can use. I just want to know what's the best way to store them in my app. Or otherwise said, HOW to store them in my app. I've heard of Core Data, NSDictionary, NSArray and I'm not sure what's the best way for me to place all that amount of images in one database.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. If your talking about storing the images, all that you need to do is drop the folder of images into your project (drag and drop the folder under the left column in XCode). If your talking about the strings to access them, then NSDictionary would be a great way to do it, where you store the title as the key and value, then just use that to access the correct image. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, that is much closer. Alright, NSDictionary sounds like a good idea, because sometimes I may need to retrieve several images for one criteria specified by the user. So, I guess now I just need to find a good tutorial on how to use NSDictionary. Can you advise me something specific?

Comment: Again though, the dictionary is a 1-to-1 type deal. If you need to be able to return a range of answer, you may want to use an NSMutableArray. This all depends on how you plan to retrieve the data. I do not know of any good tutorials right off, but I'm sure they are out there :) I would definitely shy away from Core Data, as that gets very complex quickly.

Comment: Not Core Data huh? Yeah, I thought so too. Alright, once again, just so I'm 99% sure :) Here's what I want to do with those images: Once the user types some criteria in the text field I want to extract all the images from my app that coincide with that criteria and place them in a UIScrollView so he could swipe through them. That's it! Now... NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Well if you are doing it based on criteria for the picture, then you may want to setup a dictionary, where the keys can be the names of the picture and store the properties as values under those keys... this is a difficult question because what to use REALLY depends on EXACT situations, uses and so on. I apologize for being vague-ish, but there really are just a million ways to skin the cat on this one :)

Comment: Well, I think that answers my question. Thanks a lot for your help KineticStack... I'm done bugging you... for today :)